# Integrate core-plot and wax?

Tags: iphone, core-plot, iphone-wax

Has anyone managed to use core-plot from wax?

I have been trying recently, but got stumped on NSDecimal. Wax does not want to deal with it. How can i get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in working around the NSDecimal system by rewriting the parts which used it.